# Has Microsoft introduced a bug in Bingbot such that it crawls non-existent images?

Tags: web-crawlers, 404, crawl-errors, bingbot

I've started receiving requests for paths such as `/scale/jackets/00000086/80x80_P2_G1715325W.JPG`
several times a day from the Bingbot. This started a couple of days ago.

Anybody know why this is?

Comment: How much of that path exists on your site?  Do you have a *scale* directory?  Do you sell jackets?  Do you have images that are named something similar to this?

Comment: The site has nothing related to that path or the file name. I like your line of questioning though. Thanks for asking to clarify that.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this type of behaviour from both Googlebot and Bingbot before.  It is almost never caused by a bug in the crawler itself.  It is usually caused by a bug in a website that they crawl that has links to your site or text URLs in the page  that look like that.

When it happens, it is almost always a scraper site that has copied your content and re-mixed it with the content of another site.   People who build sites like that to spam the search engines are not usually too careful with the links.

Unfortunately, Bing Webmaster Tools doesn't tell you *where* it found the links that it crawled.  It only tells you the number of links that it found to your pages.    If Googlebot starts crawling these links, then you should be able to find their source in Google Webmaster Tools.